# Is possible to get Image GPS location coordinates from a video url?

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I'm building a Flutter App where the user can fetch a video and it's location.

I'm trying to get the GSP location of the videos based on its metadata, but, I didn't found a way to do it yet.

Is possible to do it? What's the best way?

Edit: I put "GPS" in the question to make it clear. I'm trying to discover the physical position where the video was taken. I also added "Flutter" to the question to make it clear that I'm facing the problem of solving this problem in a Flutter App.

.......................

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.